# haskell System.Process.createProcess redirect stdout and stderr

Tags: unix, haskell, io

How can I redirect std_in and std_err to a file using `createProcess` in  `System.Process`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `std_in` and `std_err` fields of the `CreateProcess` type:

```
foo cmd fin ferr =
    withFile fin  ReadMode  $ \hin  ->
    withFile ferr WriteMode $ \herr -> do
        (_, _, _, ph) <- createProcess (proc cmd [])
            { std_in  = UseHandle hin
            , std_err = UseHandle herr
            }
        waitForProcess ph
```